# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). I'm getting an error while showing the current account address on the frontend

Tags: metamask, dapps, react

I'm building a buy me coffee dapp.
[image: But I'm getting this error]

Why am I getting error in line 63
[image]

[image]

I want to show the current account address on the frontend but getting error .
What is the error here? How do I solve this?

Thanks in advance!